# Can the word "cooking" also be used to describe something that is "still in the process of being developed"?

Tags: meaning

Aside, from the obvious meaning of the word "cooking" (food), can "cooking" also be used to describe something that is "still in the process of being developed" or something along the lines of that meaning? 
For example: The company is cooking new products for the next quarter, or Their new product is still cooking in the factory.
I believe I've seen this usage somewhere before, but googling it doesn't give me an answer.

Comment: Informally, yes.

Comment: You can also use various synonyms for *cooking* —a pregnant woman has *a bun in the oven*, an idea that hasn't been well thought-out is *half-baked*, projects in development that have been moved down the list of priorities are *on the back burner*, etc. These are all pretty idiomatic, though, so you want to have a good handle on them before you use one. You wouldn't want to say that a pregnant woman was *simmering a baby*, for example, but you could say that a would-be author *has a book simmering*. I'd understand both of your examples, but neither of them sounds quite natural to me.

Comment: Yes, and similarly for related expressions: *That version of the product is only half-baked.*

Comment: Usually used in the idiom "cook up" or "cooking up", and often with "a scheme" as the object of "up".

Answer (score 2):

Your memory is correct. One can certainly use *cooking* "to describe something that is 'still in the process of being developed" or something along the lines of that meaning."

Dictionary.com:

> [*cook*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cooking?s=t): to be in
>   preparation; develop
>
> "Plans for the new factory have been cooking for several years."

Oxford Dictionaries:

> [*be cooking*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cook): be happening or planned
>
> "What's cooking on the alternative fuels front?"

Answer (score 0):

It's slang - see [cooking (definition 7c)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cook--up) - and often used with the preposition 'up'

> to be in preparation; develop: "Plans for the new factory have been cooking for several years." (dictionary.com)

I wouldn't say "the new product is still cooking in the factory", but you could write:

> The company is cooking up several new products this quarter.
>
> I have a new novel cooking.
>
> They are *cooking up* a scheme to fool their neighbor.
> (*Merriam-Webster*, ["cook up"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cook%20up), slightly modified example)